# Indirect eval call in strict mode

Tags: javascript, eval, ecmascript-5

I understand about how `eval()` works in non-strict contexts, however the case of using `eval()` in strict mode has completely befuddled me.  When `eval()` is called directly in the global scope, variables are kept inside the new `eval()` scope:

```
'use strict';
eval('var a = 1;');
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

However, if I perform an *indirect* call to `eval()` in the global scope (should be the same thing, right?), it acts as though it is not in strict mode (if you don't believe me, see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSLJq/3/)):

```
'use strict';
(0, eval)('var a = 1;'); // indirect call to eval
console.log(a); // 1???
```

<sub>For an explanation of what `(0, eval)` does: see [Why does google main page use (0, obj.func)(args) syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535601/why-does-google-main-page-use-0-obj-funcargs-syntax).</sub>

At least according to my understanding of how `eval()` is supposed to work in strict mode, it is meant to (no matter whether `eval()` is called directly or indirectly) create a new scope for variables defined in the `eval()` call, however this doesn't seem to be the case here. (ECMA-262 spec 5th ed [10.4.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2))

This is the case in all major browsers (including Internet Explorer 10, Chrome 30 and Firefox 24) so I don't think it's a bug.  Aren't they both meant to do the same thing, and if not, why is this the case?

<sub>Note: yes, I know the "dangers" of using `eval()` - I simply want to understand the logic behind this :)</sub>

Comment: Feels like a bug to me. How did you execute the code above? Which browser/JS interpreter?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: in the JSFiddle given, Chrome 30.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Firefox 24 and IE10 also exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: Great question. Working on it :) Someone might beat me to it though.

Comment: Same thing with Safari 6, webkit nightly, and opera.

Comment: This article get through your question with simple code comparison in direct all and direct call without abstract conception,easy to digest,check it:https://zenplanent.blogspot.com/2021/07/unravel-eval-in-closure.html

Comment: It finally clicked when I looked at [comma operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which is the `(0,eval)` bit.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### tl;dr

The second `(0, eval)('var a = 1;');` case is in fact not a direct call.

You can see this more prevalently in:

```
(function(){ "use strict"
    var x = eval;
    x("var y = 10"); // look at me all indirect
    window.y;// 10
    eval("var y = 11");
    window.y;// still 10, direct call in strict mode gets a new context
})();
```

The issue can be seen in:

> If the eval code is strict code, then (me: fix context)

But strict eval code is defined as:

> Eval code is strict eval code if it begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive or if the call to eval is a direct call.

Since the call is not direct, the eval code is not strict eval code - and the execution is on global scope.

---

First of all great question.

"Eval Code" is more general than direct or indirect call to `eval`.

Let's check the exact specification [for the `eval` function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1)

> 15.1.2.1 eval (x)
>
> When the eval function is called with one argument x, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is not String, return x.
> 2. Let prog be the ECMAScript code that is the result of parsing x as a Program. If the parse fails, throw a SyntaxError exception (but see also clause 16).
> 3. Let evalCtx be the result of **establishing a new execution context** (10.4.2) for the eval code prog.
> 4. Let result be the result of evaluating the program prog.
> 5. Exit the running execution context evalCtx, restoring the previous execution context.
>      ...

So, let's explore what 10.4.2 tells us, you cited that - in specific let's look at the first clause:

> If there is no calling context or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then ... Initialise the execution context as if it was a global execution context

#### So what is a direct call?

> A direct call to the eval function is one that is expressed as a CallExpression that meets the following two conditions:
>
> The Reference that is the result of evaluating the MemberExpression in the CallExpression has an environment record as its base value and its reference name is "eval".
>
> The result of calling the abstract operation GetValue with that Reference as the argument is the standard built-in function defined in 15.1.2.1.

So, what's the `MemberExpression` in both cases?

In `eval('var a = 1;');` indeed the result of evaluating it has a reference name `eval` and calling `GetValue` resolution on it returns the built in function.

In `(0, eval)('var a = 1;');` the result of evaluating the member expression does *not* have a reference name `eval`. (It does resolve to the built in function on GetValue though).

#### What are reference names anyway?

Section [8.7 in the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) tells us:

> A Reference is a resolved name binding. A Reference consists of three components, the base value, the referenced name and the Boolean valued strict reference flag. The base value is either undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record (10.2.1). A base value of undefined indicates that the reference could not be resolved to a binding. The referenced name is a String.

This requires us to look into the `GetReferencedName`:

> GetReferencedName(V). Returns the referenced name component of the reference V.

So, while the expression `(0,eval) === eval` is true, when evaluating the function, this is actually an indirect call because of naming.

### May I offer the `Function` constructor instead :)?

Comment: Okay, not bad.  However, this doesn't explain step 3 - that if it's in strict mode, create a new scope for the eval call.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I have to admit EcmaScript 6's "If direct is true and the code that made the direct call to eval is strict code, then let strictCaller be true. Otherwise, let strictCaller be false." is a lot clearer. ES5 makes you walk the extra mile. Strict mode code is defined as : "Eval code is strict eval code if it begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive or if the call to eval is a direct call" - the call is a direct call so actually - the condition in step 3 is false.

Comment: I meant the call is _not_ a direct call.

Comment: So am I right in saying that an indirect call to eval is not strict unless the body contains `"use strict"`, and therefore since it actually isn't strict mode, this new scope isn't created?

Comment: Yes, you are (assuming "use strict" is in the directive prologue -as the first thing there). This is exactly what the specification means :)

Comment: Wow, yet another quirk to remember... ;)  Yes, I'll take the `Function` constructor any day - this was just for curiosity or _that random day_ that I'm required to do something weird in strict code. :D

Comment: This is a great question, with an amazing answer to boot. Thanks, for some incredibly insightful commentary!