# What is meant by (0, somefunc)(args)

Tags: javascript, function

I've been going through some of gmails javascript (writing an extension) and I've seen `(0, _.ab)(a)`, or variations, all over the places. What does this achieve?

I've tried some tests such as

```
function a(a,b,c){ console.dir(a+b+c); }
(0, a)(1,2,3)
```

However I can't work out why they wouldn't just call `a(1,2,3)` directly. Does calling it using `(0,a)` have some odd benefit?

I've made a jsperf (http://jsperf.com/direct-vs-0-func-calls) to test this, and `a(1)` vs `(0,a)(1)` seem identical.

*Edit: As Far as I can make out google only use it where they need to directly call a function, such as `if ((0, _.wa)(a))` (taken from gmail's source)*

Comment: I suspect it's a by-product of a minifier or transpiler.

Comment: That was what my thoughts were, but why would the minifier do that?

Comment: @Pointy Wouldn't Closure Compiler (used on many Google products) just eliminate that code entirely?

Comment: Are you sure the first function isn't returning a function? It could be a chained call.

Comment: @Tibos I would certainly expect it to, but then again I know precisely nothing about how it works :)

Comment: When you have jQuery, this works too: `(0, $)('body');`, it's basically the same as just calling  `$('body');`... Wut.

Comment: @Cerbrus And this is surprising, because `$` isn't a function.

Comment: @Zirak: With jQuery included, it is.

Comment: That's so surprising.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19357978/1348195

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `(0, func)()` syntax ensures that the context (`this`) in the called function `func` is the global context.

For example:

```
var myContext = {
    func: function () { 
        console.log(this);
    }
};

myContext.func();        // => myContext
(0, myContext.func)();   // => window
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there some documentation on this, somewhere?

Comment: Ahh, eliminating the scope chain to access global objects? Clever.

Comment: ... the "comma operator". I always forget those are also operators.