# JavaScript object functions and `this` when unbound and returned in expression/parens

Tags: javascript, this

Lines 1-2 and 4-5 make sense in terms of the `this` returned. What am I missing about line 3? I thought it would return `window` similar to lines 4-5. Is there another pattern not in these 5 that could help demonstrate why?

```
foo = { bar : function () { return this } }

foo.bar() // ==> foo

(foo.bar)() // ==> foo / but why?

(foo.bar ? foo.bar : $.noop)() // ==> window

(foo.bar || 0)() // ==> window
```

Comment: As I understand it, there is, between `(foo.bar)` and `foo.bar`(line 2) no difference. Its just inserting unnecessary brackets like ` 1 + 2 * 3 ` is the same as ` 1 + ( 2 * 3 ) `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The grouping operator does not destroy property references, which are provoking the *method* call.

This is explicitly mentioned in [the spec](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6):

> NOTE: This algorithm does not apply [GetValue](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) to the result of
>   evaluating `Expression`. The principal motivation for this is so that
>   operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesised
>   expressions.

In your lines 4 and 5, it's not the parenthesis but the operators (`?:` and `||`) that de-reference the property and yield the "unbound" function.

Comment: Nice answer, there are actually common tricks to "get around" this, the most common I've seen is `(0,foo.bar)` to break the reference or cause an indirect call without adding a line. It gives rise to [an interesting example with `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357978/indirect-eval-call-in-strict-mode) too :)

Answer (score 3):

`foo.bar` here is an anonymous function.

It might make more sense if you split it up into different lines:

```
foo = {
    bar: function() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

So, when you call `foo.bar`, you're getting `function() { return this; }`. On line two, you call that function directly (`foo.bar()`), so it returns `this`, the instance of the object (`foo`).

On line three, you get the same result because you're not *only* asking for the anonymous function, but executing that function as well:

```
(foo.bar); // (function() { return this; }); A reference to the function
(foo.bar)(); // (function() { return this; })(); Actually calling the function
```

Because in the latter case, you're executing the function as you did in line two, the result is the same (`foo`).

In lines four and five, however, as Bergi said, the operators you use dereference them from the function, which leaves you with a `Window` object rather than `foo`.