# How to send JSON inside of class syntax to an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, router

Let's say I have a normal `mjs` file and an API such as this:

```
// Storage.mjs
class Storage {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.json = JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}
var store = new Storage('eMart', 2);

// server.js
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    data = fs.readFileSync('website/js/storage.mjs'),
    convert = JSON.parse(data);

var app = express(),
    server = app.listen(3000, initialize);

console.log(convert);

function initialize() {
    console.log("Local Host Initialized.");
}

app.use(express.static('website'));
```

My goal is to send the JSON data to API which is inside of `class syntax`, but every time Node keeps throwing `undefined` and an error like this picture;

[image]

Most of people's question was sending data from API to specific `js` file which was totally opposite of my case. It was hard to find solution from there.

Are there any proper ways to pass JSON data to API?

Comment: There's no data inside of the `mjs` file except 2 (eMart is apparently defined elsewhere). You can't just read a module file and pretend it's JSON. JSON is a specific format for text to encode data (not classes and the like). See http://json.org/ for specifics.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My bad. value eMart is actually a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want?

```js
// assume this is loaded with fs.readFileSync
const mjs = `
class Storage {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.json = JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}
var store = new Storage('eMart', 2);  // I assume you missed the quote here
`;

eval(mjs);  // You can't just convert an js file into a JSON, you have to eval it first(not safe, use it with caution)

let result = JSON.parse(store.json);  // Since the file outputs a variable called "store" and it has a "json" property

console.log(result);
```

The `server.js` snippet

```
// server.js
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    data = fs.readFileSync('website/js/storage.mjs');  

(0, eval)(data);  // indirect eval
var convert = JSON.parse(store.json);

var app = express(),
    server = app.listen(3000, initialize);

console.log(convert);

function initialize() {
    console.log("Local Host Initialized.");
}

app.use(express.static('website'));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but Node is still saying an error which is `store is not defind.`.

Comment: If the eval runs without an error. It probably because your code is running in `use strict` mode so it failed compiling, in that case try to declare it first like above that I just updated.

Comment: Sorry, the predefinition seems do not work in `use strict` either. Try to make an `Indirect eval call` to bypass this behavior like the update above, here's the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357978/indirect-eval-call-in-strict-mode

Comment: Got it. Thanks for detailed answering.